# Dynamic chart is not working properly (highcharts)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

The problem I am encountering is that the black line is doing some funky stuff compared to the blue line. If you scroll in the middle or somewhere else (use bottom scroll tool), you can clearly see that the black line is changing its shape, while the blue line holds its shape, strange. This only happens when you use the scroll tool.

How can I prevent the black line changing its shape? Copy this code and replace it with the JSfiddle to see the problem:

```
$(function () {

    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global : {
            useUTC : false
        }
    });
    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart : {
            events : {
                load : function () {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function () {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    }, 1000);

                    var series1 = this.series[1];
                    setInterval(function () {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                        series1.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            buttons: [{
                count: 1,
                type: 'minute',
                text: '1M'
            }, {
                count: 5,
                type: 'minute',
                text: '5M'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }],
            inputEnabled: false,
            selected: 0
        },

        title : {
            text : 'Live random data'
        },

        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'diagram1',
            data : (function () {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data1 = [], time = (new Date()).getTime(), i;

                for (i = -999; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                    data1.push([
                        time + i * 1000,
                        Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
                    ]);
                }
                return data1;
            }())
        },
        {
            name : 'diagram2',
            data : (function () {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data2 = [], time = (new Date()).getTime(), i;

                for (i = -999; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                    data2.push([
                        time + i * 1000,
                        Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
                    ]);
                }
                return data2;
            }())
        }]
    });

});
```

The only thing I have done is to add an extra dynamic line (black one) to the diagram. Here is the original code without the black line. [Review original code](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/dynamic-update/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of the movement in the black line is the redraw and the animation function of the chart. For some reason the first series(blue line) doesn't show animation after calling **`addPoint`** so you don't see the movement. The second parameter in the `addPoint` function is **`redraw`**. Setting it to false for the second series(black line) will stop the movement when updating the points:

```
series1.addPoint([x, y], false, true);
```

Here's the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6u14ec3j/).

Comment: @PawełFus Can you please shed some light on why the first series doesn't animate when updating the points or why does the second series do?

Comment: Will I continue to do this if I add series2, series3, series4 with [....,false,true]?

Comment: Of course. Only series number one seems to be different than the others. http://jsfiddle.net/6u14ec3j/1/

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this forum, I have rated your answer. Thank you :)